# Hiding files in public folder with random names paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, file-upload, paperclip

I have a problem, I would like to store files outside the public folder using paperclip (to make them private), it would be very simple, just configure the :path option, but to retrieve those files (many of them images) I would need a controller method (ie. get_file), making very slow when you display a list of files with the "thumb" images. I was thinking to use a **random name** to store the files in the public, some cryptic name with SHA1 or something, how hard would it be to access a file.?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you make sure that the directory is never listed and the name is really random (does not depend on the real name) and long enough (16 alphanumeric characters should be ok) this is a feasible and common method to do it.

Comment: Caveat: this is classic security by obscurity, with all its disadvantages - anyone can access the file once the URL is known. If you're only trying to prevent access by random guessing, this can be useful; for making the files private, not so much. ("Hey, Piskvor has a private photo at /images/a65578b0eda778.jpg, check it out!")

Comment: If using a "hard to guess" number is security by obscurity, every encryption is, too. Anyway, thanks for pointing out the problem with forwarding "private" links. However, it would always be possible to save the file instead of forwarding the link, so not such a big deal.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, I knew that as long other people can't list your folders it has some security but I wanted to know if there were any work arounds to make this happen, I have tried this with **nginx, passenger** and when I try to list any of the public folders it redirects me to other location.